# How do you program a formula to fill in the next available cell in a row?

Tags: excel-formula

I want the output of the formula to, get an answer, fill in one cell, then if it has more outputs move on to subsequent cells and fill them in order (A1, A2, A3...). If this is not possible then have the output able to list the results in one cell. Example if you are tracking tasks and have dates completed for each of these similar tasks and you want a list of tasks that aren't completed or out of date to be generated for easy cut and paste to send in an email.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think you need to look into writing a macro to do something like this dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Formulas or User Defined Functions (UDF) are by design meant to only return a result and not modify other elements. Of course people have figured out workarounds to circumvent this restriction but I don't think that's an approach you want to take.

What you could use is an array formula that would output more than 1 result. You would write the formula out highlighting multiple cells and complete by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. You would have to know the maximum number of expected results and scale your formula to the same number of cells. For more info on Array Formulas you can visit: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-3be0c791-3f89-4644-a062-8e6e9ecee523

Otherwise I will have to agree with Mr. Bananas that it will require a custom VBA script. Hope this helps.